# What is this disrtibution being called? $g_{r}(x) = cx^{-r}\chi _{(1,\infty)}(x)$

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a pdf $g_{r}: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, r>1,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $g_{r}(x) = cx^{-r}\chi _{(1,\infty)}(x)$. I am currently creating a list of all distributions we have covered in my stochastics lectures and homework and I wondered if this distribution has a name respectively if it is a special case of a more general distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

Comment: Yes, I can see it.Thanks!

Comment: Then you might answer your question and accept it.